# Regex not matching hyphen and other punctuation

Tags: regex, vb.net

Why is the following regex not matching a hyphen (or ampersand, period, or comma, though I have excluded them from the below character class for the moment)?  I'm trying to match strings like...

```
h eh - l ow 1
```

...(which is a phonetic representation of the word "hello") and the match is failing when there is a hyphen in the string (same for ampersand, et al, listed above).

```
Regex.Match(SomeText, "^(\b(?:aa|ae|ah|ao|aw|ax|ay|b|ch|d|dh|eh|er|ey|f|g|h|ih|iy|jh|k|l|m|n|ng|ow|oy|p|r|s|sh|t|th|uh|uw|v|w|y|z|zh|[12\-])\b ?)+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

This pattern...

```
^(\b(?:a|b|-)\b ?)+$
```

...works, according to regex101.com, and it's essentially the exact same pattern, so I don't see why the longer one isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your understanding of word boundaries that's at fault.  But don't feel bad, that's one of the most misunderstood regex constructs.  You need to be aware that the regex engine doesn't know what a word is, as we define it.  To it, a word is simply a sequence of one or more word characters (i.e. characters that are matched by `\w`).

But however you define them, a regex doesn't really match words anyway.  It can only ever "see" two characters at any given time: the next one and the previous one.  What `\b` matches is a position that's followed by a word character and not preceded by one (which could be the beginning of a word), or preceded by a word character and not followed by one (possibly the end of a word).

You could make your regex work by means of strategic grouping like [zx81 did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966158/20938), but you're better off just getting rid of the word boundaries.  Their purpose is to make sure the word you're matching isn't part of a longer word.  You don't need them because that's already clear from the context: every word is (1) preceded by a space or the beginning of the string, and (2) followed by a space or the end of the string.

```
"(?in)^((aa|ae|ah|ao|aw|ax|ay|b|ch|d|dh|eh|er|ey|f|g|h|ih|iy|jh|k|l|m|n|ng|ow|oy|p|r|s|sh|t|th|uh|uw|v|w|y|z|zh|[12]|-)( |$))+$"
```

In case you're wondering, the `n` in `(?in)` turns on ExplicitCapture mode, which makes groups non-capturing. ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Thank you for the explanation (as well as an answer, of course!)  I make use of regex with some regularity, but you are correct about my (mis-)understanding of word boundaries.  Always more to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Because the word boundaries `\b` cannot not match on either side of the lone hyphens `-`. We need to move the boundaries to where they only surround text or digits.

This will work:

```
^(?:\b(?:aa|ae|ah|ao|aw|ax|ay|b|ch|d|dh|eh|er|ey|f|g|h|ih|iy|jh|k|l|m|n|ng|ow|oy|p|r|s|sh|t|th|uh|uw|v|w|y|z|zh|[12])\b|[ -])+$
```

See **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/22)**.

Note that in VB.NET this will be easier to read if you use free-spacing mode:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex( _
    "^                # start of string" & chr(10) & _
    "(?:              # non-capture group" & chr(10) & _
    "  \b               # word boundary" & chr(10) & _
    "  (?:              # non-capture group" & chr(10) & _
    "       aa|ae|ah|ao|aw|ax|ay|b|ch|d|dh|eh|" & chr(10) & _
    "       er|ey|f|g|h|ih|iy|jh|k|l|m|n|ng|ow|" & chr(10) & _
    "       oy|p|r|s|sh|t|th|uh|uw|v|w|y|z|zh" & chr(10) & _
    "   )               # end group" & chr(10) & _
    "   \b              # word boundary" & chr(10) & _
    "   |               # OR" & chr(10) & _
    "   [ 12-]          # one of these characters" & chr(10) & _
    ")+               # repeat" & chr(10) & _
    "$                # end of string", _
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

Also, just for fun, note that the long alternation of letters can be shortened to

```
aa|er|ng|[ac-eijs-uz]h|[aou]w|[aeio]y|a[eox]|[bdf-hk-npr-tvwyz]
```

Comment: I'm surprised that my fast answer that included an explanation, code and optimization tweak didn't help.